# Upload Textarea Content as a file

Tags: file-upload, textarea

I want to ***upload the content of a textarea as a file*** because content exceed max_input_vars limit in php.ini. In the future maybe it will increase so I prefer to upload it as a file ^^

I show the content to the user in a textarea, so it is editable :) And then click "Save" and send the content of the textarea as a file. How can I do ?

````
<span onclick="data_save();">Save</span>

<textarea id="textarea">
    <?php
        print_r($tab);
    ?>
</textarea>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
        echo file_get_contents('/var/www/'.$jsdir.'/jquery-2.1.4.min.js');
    ?>
    
    function data_save()
    {
        var textToWrite = document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML;
        var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([ textToWrite ], { type: 'text/plain' });
        var fileNameToSaveAs = "ecc.plist";

        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
        if (window.webkitURL != null)
        {
            // Chrome allows the link to be clicked without actually adding it to the DOM.
            downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        } else {
            // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM before it can be clicked.
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
            downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
            downloadLink.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        }
        
        // downloadLink.click();
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data_save.php',
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(retour)
            {
                if (retour.indexOf('Oups') != -1)
                    alert(retour);
            },
            error: function(obj, text, error)
            {
                alert("Oups.. " + obj.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
        
</script>```
````

Answer (score 0):

It not possible, user must download and the upload the file by himself....